# How to graph the second derivatives of coupled non-linear second order ODEs in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, differential-equations, odeint

I am very new to Python and have written this code to model the motion of a spring pendulum:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from numpy import sin, cos, pi, array
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

init = array([0,pi/18,0,0]) 

def deriv(z, t):
    x, y, dxdt, dydt = z
    dx2dt2=(4+x)*(dydt)**2-5*x+9.81*cos(y)
    dy2dt2=(-9.81*sin(y)-2*(dxdt)*(dydt))/(0.4+x)

    return np.array([dxdt, dydt, dx2dt2, dy2dt2])

time = np.linspace(0.0,10.0,1000)
sol = odeint(deriv,init,time)

plt.xlabel("time")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.plot(time, sol)
plt.show()
```

But it gives me the graphs of `x`, `dxdt`, `y` and `dydt` instead of `dx2dt2` and `dy2dt2` (which are the second derivatives of `x` and `y` respectively). How do I alter my code to graph the second derivatives instead?

Comment: Can you include the original differential equation you want to solve and how you turned it into a system of first order differential equations? I suspect the answer is simply that to get d2xdt2 you want to call `plot((time[1:] + time[:-1])/2,np.diff(sol[:,1])/np.diff(time))` and `plot((time[1:] + time[:-1])/2,np.diff(sol[:,3])/np.diff(time))`.

Comment: @user545424 I wanted to solve a system of coupled ODEs. The original equations are `x'' = (0.18+x)*(y')^2-51x+9.81*cos(y)` and `(0.18+x)y''+2x'y'=-10*sin(y)`, where both x and y are with respect to time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return value of `odeint` is the solution to `z(t)` which you have defined to be `z = [x,y,x',y']`. Therefore the second derivative is not a part of the solution returned by `odeint`. You can approximate the second derivative of `x` and `y` by taking finite differences of the returned values of the first derivatives.

For example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from numpy import sin, cos, pi, array
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

init = array([0,pi/18,0,0]) 

def deriv(z, t):
    x, y, dxdt, dydt = z
    dx2dt2=(4+x)*(dydt)**2-5*x+9.81*cos(y)
    dy2dt2=(-9.81*sin(y)-2*(dxdt)*(dydt))/(0.4+x)

    return np.array([dxdt, dydt, dx2dt2, dy2dt2])

time = np.linspace(0.0,10.0,1000)
sol = odeint(deriv,init,time)

x, y, xp, yp = sol.T

# compute the approximate second order derivative by computing the finite
# difference between values of the first derivatives
xpp = np.diff(xp)/np.diff(time)
ypp = np.diff(yp)/np.diff(time)

# the second order derivatives are now calculated at the midpoints of the
# initial time array, so we need to compute the midpoints to plot it
xpp_time = (time[1:] + time[:-1])/2

plt.xlabel("time")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.plot(time, x, label='x')
plt.plot(time, y, label='y')
plt.plot(time, xp, label="x'")
plt.plot(time, yp, label="y'")
plt.plot(xpp_time, xpp, label="x''")
plt.plot(xpp_time, ypp, label="y''")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Alternatively, since you already have a function to compute the second order derivatives from the solution, you can just call that function:

```
plt.plot(time, deriv(sol.T,time)[2], label="x''")
plt.plot(time, deriv(sol.T,time)[3], label="y''")
```